# Need to flush Cache every day Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento, caching, cron, magento-1.9

After each midnight I get the message

> One or more of the Cache Types are invalidated

in my admin panel, even if I haven't changed any product etc.
Maybe it is not the end of the world, but it makes me nervous when something isn't right.

It started when I updated to Magento version 1.9.x.x
How can I solve this?

Is it a `cron` job fault or something else?
My `cron` job looks like this, if that is of help to the cause:

```
*/3 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/USER/domains/DOMAIN/public_html/cron.php > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check for all your Magento crons running around this hour ? Chances are high that the invalidation is triggered by the cron that applies all catalog rules, which changes products' price and then requires a cache refresh.

If you're not able to visualize your Magento crons, I suggest that you install [Aoe_Scheduler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I like to have as little extensions as possible installed but if there is no other way to see what might cause this I might give this extension a try.

Comment: @Ronnie79 you can also check the running hours of your cronjobs directly in the config.xml of the modules. Take a tour in this file in the Mage_Catalogrule module. As a side note, this extension is really a must have, having a visual interface for the config of your crons, their execution time and their success/errors is almost vital. I work in a Magento specialized company, and this module is part of the package we install on every project we maintain.